# Основы asyncio: остановка сопрограмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Пытаюсь осилить asyncio, пишу приложение, качающее нечто по http в несколько «потоков». (*Документация очень странная, большинство примеров на docs.python.org запускают ровно одну задачу через loop_until_complete (зачем вообще asyncio для одной задачи?), запуск нескольких задач я нашёл только аж где-то на Хабре.*) Запускаю это всё дело примерно так:

```
class Listener(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def listen(self):
        response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', self.url)
        try:
            while True:
                data = yield from response.content.read(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                print(len(data))
        finally:
            response.close()

for url in urls:
    l = Listener(url)
    task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(l.listen())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

И, собственно, как это всё дело корректно остановить по Ctrl+C? Или как его корректно запустить, чтобы потом можно было корректно остановить? В приведённом выше коде на меня ругаются `Exception ignored in: Task was destroyed but it is pending!`, перехват исключения и `loop.close()` не помогают, `cancel()` у тасков тоже не помогает *(ну это поведение cancel хотя бы задокументировано)*. Одна из ссылок в гугле советовала заводить под это дело ещё один поток, но неужели без двух потоков жизни нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, надо не только комбинировать всё и сразу, но ещё и применять упущенную мной из виду функцию `loop.stop()` и цеплять сигналы к loop'у (как всё сложно...):

```
def stop():
    for task in listeners:
        task.cancel()
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, stop)
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, stop)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Правда, теперь мне после завершения всего пишут `Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in:` (даже на logging.DEBUG), но, если верить гуглу, это какие-то глюки в aiohttp, а это уже совсем другая история

Answer (score 0):

<sup>комментарий к вопросу:</sup>

> большинство примеров на docs.python.org запускают ровно одну задачу через loop_until_complete (зачем вообще asyncio для одной задачи?),

Это всё равно что сказать: зачем функции в С, если по умолчанию только одна функция `main()` всегда запускается.

Основная задача может создать сколько угодно подзадач, которые также могут исполняться одновременно. Вот [пример кода, который создаёт множество (макс. `limit`) параллельных соединений, используя только один `loop.run_until_complete()` вызов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722204/4279).