# Корректно остановить скритп с asyncio.event_loop

Tags: python, python-3.5, asyncio, event-loop

Пишем простой код:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial

handle = [None]

async def callback():
    print(datetime.now())
    handle[0] = asyncio.get_event_loop().call_later(
        10,
        partial(asyncio.ensure_future, callback()))

def main():
    try:
        handle[0] = asyncio.ensure_future(callback())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Запускаем и через ~15 сек. снимаем через Ctrl+C

```
$ ./period.py
2016-09-09 14:08:05.392415
2016-09-09 14:08:10.393921
^Csys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'callback' was never awaited
```

RuntimeWarning как бы намекает, что выход не совсем корректный.
Как корректно завершится?

Решение нашлось: нужно заменить `partial` на `lambda`.
Ошибка происходила из за того, что при вызове `callback()` создавалась короутина, которая никуда не была привязана.
Таким образом, корректный код будет следующий:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial

handle = [None]

async def callback():
    print(datetime.now())
    handle[0] = asyncio.get_event_loop().call_later(
        10,
        lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(callback()))
    loop.stop()

def main():
    try:
        handle[0] = asyncio.ensure_future(callback())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        handle[0].cancel()
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Быть может, вот это поможет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429692/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b-asyncio-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [asyncio: корректная остановка не своих сопрограмм](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433554/23044)

Comment: К сожалению не помогает.
Можно и вовсе обойтись без Ctrl+C.
Просто добавить в конце функции `callback()` вызов `loop.stop()`

Comment: Всё дело было в `partial(asyncio.ensure_future, callback())`
Если её заменить на `lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(callback())` всё завершается корректно.
А происходит это от того, что вызов callback() порождает короутину, которую никто не ждал и при окончании потеряли.